# How to display a pop up with the contents of a

Tags: java, time, printing, calculator, clock

I'm trying to make a program the takes in the amount of seconds and then pops up with the time after midnight. To do this I've wrote the following code, although I can't get it to print back the time. I can have it display in the console but I'd rather it pop up. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

public class Exercise4 {

```
private static final int MinsInHour = 60;
private static final int SecsInMinute = 60;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputseconds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many seconds? <> ");
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(inputseconds);

}

private static String timeConversion(int seconds) {

    final int MinsInHour = 60;
    final int SecsInMinute = 60;

        int minutes = seconds / SecsInMinute;
        seconds -= minutes * SecsInMinute;

        int hours = minutes / MinsInHour;
        minutes -= hours * MinsInHour;

    return hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have another command after `return`. I've reversed the last 2 lines for you.

```
private static String timeConversion(int seconds) {

    final int MinsInHour = 60;
    final int SecsInMinute = 60;

        int minutes = seconds / SecsInMinute;
        seconds -= minutes * SecsInMinute;

        int hours = minutes / MinsInHour;
        minutes -= hours * MinsInHour;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");
    return hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
}
```

Comment: Exercise4.java:26: error: no suitable method found for showMessageDialog(String)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");
     I'm getting this back, any ideas?